# Pyenv not auto activating

Tags: python, virtualenv, boxen, pyenv

I have pyenv installed in my environment and up to this weekend (when I installed 'Kivy') my pyenv/local setup has been working fine. But now when I go to my various python project directories, pyenv does not automatically activate the right python version properly.

E.g.

I create an environment using pyenv like this,

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.3.2 work
```

I make and go into a dir called `work` and have a `.python-version` file with the text `work` as the sole content.

Pyenv detects that my environment is `work` using this file but my python version is not python `3.3.2` instead it's `2.7.9`.

For some reason, something happened, and all of my pyenv virtual environments use `2.7.9` as opposed to the python version they were created with.

When I run `which python` I get,

```
/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin/python
```

when I go to the pyenv version directory and run

```
$ cat pyvenv.cfg                                                                                                                                                                                           
home = /opt/boxen/pyenv/versions/3.3.2/bin
include-system-site-packages = false 
version = 3.3.2
```

However, if I run `pyenv activate` I my python version switches to python `3.3.2` (or the appropriate version for a given env).

Question is, how do I get pyenv to auto activate the environment's python version as it did before (before I did something to break it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like, because of `which python` not saying it's the shim, you don't have the bin/shims path *first* in your `PATH` envvar. Add these lines to your shell startup script, and make sure they're at the *end*, after any other path manipulations.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
```

The `eval` line does some additional shell monkeying I think to add the `.pyenv/shims` directory...check that with an `echo $PATH` maybe.

Comment: Thanks but `pyenv` is in my path, here's my path, `export PATH="/Users/me/.autojump/bin:bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims:/opt/boxen/rbenv/bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/opt/boxen/pyenv/shims:/opt/boxen/pyenv/bin:node_modules/.bin:/opt/boxen/nodenv/shims:/opt/boxen/nodenv/bin:/opt/boxen/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"`

Comment: That's my path from my zsh startup script

Comment: @user does anything else modify it (check in an actual shell instead of looking at the script)?

Comment: Nothing modifies it, when i run echo $PATH  `/Users/me/.pyenv/bin:/Users/ahmed/.autojump/bin:bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims:/opt/boxen/rbenv/bin:/opt/boxen/ruby-build/bin:/opt/boxen/pyenv/bin:node_modules/.bin:/opt/boxen/nodenv/shims:/opt/boxen/nodenv/bin:/opt/boxen/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/sbin:/Users/ahmed/.autojump/bin:bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/shims:/opt/boxen/rbenv/bin:/opt/boxen/rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/opt/boxen/pyenv/shims:/opt/boxen/pyenv/bin:node_modules/.bin:/opt/boxen/nodenv/shims:/opt/boxen/nodenv/bin:/opt/boxen/bin:/opt/boxen/homebrew/bin:...`

Comment: It seems like my initial guess was correct `/opt/boxen/pyenv/‌​shims` is not the first (or first among places that have `python`, `pip`, etc. in it), because it's after `/opt/boxen/homebrew‌​/bin`, which `which python` is telling you it's using.

Comment: Thanks! I've gotten things straightened away now. Although I never altered anything, I wonder why this has occurred... :/