# How do you reinstall a plugin/package/app with Boxen?

Tags: macos, boxen, pyenv

My work machine is configured with Boxen and [something broke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544763/pyenv-not-auto-activating/28550980) with my `pyenv` setup. I can't figure it out but I want it was installed by boxen and I'm not sure how to reinstall a specific app or package or plugin using boxen.

We have this segment in my /manifests/site.pp file,

```
  python::plugin { 'pyenv-virtualenv':
    ensure => 'v20140705',
    source => 'yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv',
  }
```

Which basically gives boxens instructions on installing `pyenv`, I don't see any boxen command to uninstall and reinstall `pyenv`. I've tried running,

```
./boxen
```

or

```
./boxen bootstrap
```

I can use brew to uninstall/reinstall pyenv but brew will install it in it's own configuration. I want to re-run the install used by `boxen` when i first config'd my mac.